# complex json to gson

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a json data like bellow:

```
{
    total_result: 46979,
    facet: [
        {
        author: [
            {
                writter1: 409
            },
            {
                writter2: 390
            },
            {
                writter3: 273
            },
            ........................
            ......................
        ]
        },
        {
        category: [
            {
                book1: 40480
            },
            {
                book2: 6178
            },
            {
                book3: 5994
            },
            .....................
            .....................
        ]
        },
    .......................
    ......................
    ],
    results:[.........]
}
```

The data under `facet` are dynamic.
how can i format this json to gson?

my code:

```
public class ResultContainer {
    public int total_result;
    public Facet facet; 
    public List<Result> results;
}
```

and Facet class is:

```
public class Facet {
    private List<Map<String, String>> author;
    private List<Map<String, String>> category;
    private List<Map<String, String>> domain;
    private List<Map<String, String>> editor;
    private List<Map<String, String>> publisher;
    private List<Map<String, String>> tags;

    // rest of the code is getter and setter
}
```

The problem is with the `facet` part. all other part of the json is parsed to gson correctly. But not the `facet`. if I block the `public Facet facet;` from `ResultContainer` then the code works perfectly. What is the problem?

**But it is not working. how can I solve this?**

**Error:**

```
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591): Process: com.pipilika.booksearch, PID: 19591
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591): com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 32 path $.facet
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:221)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:217)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:861)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:826)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:747)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at com.pipilika.booksearch.MainActivity$AsyncBookSearch.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:235)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at com.pipilika.booksearch.MainActivity$AsyncBookSearch.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5528)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 32 path $.facet
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:388)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:210)
01-12 14:32:05.248: E/AndroidRuntime(19591):    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to what you mean when you say it "is not working"?

Comment: @aug please see my edited question. thanks

Comment: any error you are getting?

Comment: Try this online utility to convert json to pojo classes [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: could you post the json you are trying to parse?

Comment: maybe `public Facet facet;`  to  `public List<Facet> facet;` ?

Comment: @tianwei but the objects under `facet` are dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory. The json structure contains an array of 'facets' but where as your class structure declares a single object for facet. Change your class structure so that there is a list of facets like below:

```
public class ResultContainer {
    public int total_result;
    public List<Facet> facet; // this is the required change
    public List<Result> results;
}
```

Comment: That's alright, but as long as facet is always an array it doesn't matter

Comment: could you explain how the `Facet` class should look like?

Comment: Just FYI, the json structure reads something like "facet is a **list** of objects that can contain dynamic properties" it's not a 'dynamic object' rather it's an list of objects that can contain dynamic properties

Comment: The facet class is just fine, you have to update the 'ResultContainer' class as per my answer